# bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I am trying to run a ruby program and I get `bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory` When I navigate to `/usr/bin/ruby` and `ls | grep ruby` I get an output with `ruby` in it. When I try to `./ruby` I STILL get `bash: ./ruby: No such file or directory`. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ruby to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on? I am really stumped.

Comment: What does `ls -la /usr/bin/ruby` say?

Comment: Try `sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-full` and perhaps use `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1`

Comment: Maybe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists or http://superuser.com/questions/344533/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-bash-but-the-file-exists ?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug 12 20:11 /usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments on the question, your `/usr/bin/ruby` binary is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/ruby`.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug 12 20:11 /usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby
```

You should confirm that path exists (run `ls -la /etc/alternatives/ruby` to check if that path exists) and if it does not, you'll need to reinstall Ruby using your system package manager (e.g., `apt-get`), download and install Ruby from https://www.ruby-lang.org, or use a tool like [RVM](https://rvm.io).

Comment: `ls -la /etc/alternatives/ruby` gives me `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Aug 12 20:11 /etc/alternatives/ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1`

Comment: I am basically just advocating that you continue to trace the path of symlinks here, until you get to the REAL binary (or else until you reach a path that does not exist). So, does `ls -la /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1` show a real binary at that path? Rinse, repeat...

Comment: YES `ls -la /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1` gives me `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10281 Sep  3 23:16 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1` BUT `./ruby1.9.1` still gives me a no such file error

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -v`?

Comment: bash: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry this is a weird bug. I'm going to try and delete all the sym links and my versions of ruby. Then reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding a different possible cause and fix for the same `/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory` error after installing Ruby.

If, unlike the original poster here, you get this same message but on investigating find that there really is nothing at `/usr/bin/ruby`, try `/usr/local/bin/ruby --version`: it seems that some installations put the binary in `/usr/local/bin/ruby` but look for it at `/usr/bin/ruby`.

This happened to me with ruby version 1.9.3p547 on Centos. If this is what's happened, the easy fix is to create a symlink at `/usr/bin/ruby` that points to `/usr/local/bin/ruby`.

Answer (score 3):

The better option is use

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

it will always use current selected ruby in the environment, not depending on any tool

Answer (score -2):

I had this error while working on Ruby on rails project and deployment to heroku.

For ruby on rails and heroku
On you editor, find 'bin' folder then in each file remove the ruby number extension leaving 'ruby' only on the commented code. 
Thank me later